# Unable to access scrapyd interface on the server machine with public IP

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, scrapyd, scrapinghub

I am trying to run scrapyd my ubuntu server which has a public IP using the following config file named `scrapy.cfg`

```
[settings]
default = web_crawler.settings

[deploy:default]
url = http://127.0.0.1:6800/
project = web_crawler

[scrapyd]
eggs_dir = eggs
logs_dir = logs
jobs_to_keep = 5
dbs_dir = dbs
max_proc = 1
max_proc_per_cpu = 4
finished_to_keep = 100
poll_interval = 5.0
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
http_port = 6800
debug = off
runner = scrapyd.runner
application = scrapyd.app.application
launcher = scrapyd.launcher.Launcher
webroot = scrapyd.website.Root
```

After I start the scrapyd server using `scrapyd` command and deploy the spider using `scrapyd-deploy default`, I try to access the scrapyd interface in the browser `http://publicip:6800` but it just says connection refused. What could be the reason for this? There is no firewall, all ports are open.

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the deploy URL to `0.0.0.0:6800` and deploying it. Your `scrapyd` web console will also be available at `http://0.0.0.0:6800/` as this is the address you are binding.